# Delayed start-up with no current consumption after

Tags: analog, battery-operated, delay, logic-level, pmos

I have a delay circuit. My sole purpose is to disable the input from the orange line for some time after the power is on. After that this portion of the circuit should not consume any current. Here is the circuit:

[image: main pic]

There is 5 to 9 V at the top and bottom is the ground. SW3 will be closed first and then it will open when SW2 (the one at the top) closes. When that happens, C7 starts to discharge and after a while Q9 is on. I know it will open slowly but that's not important as the orange line will have voltage very rarely.

I want to have the same delay each time; that's why I've added a comparator (U1:A) to stop extra charging of C7. If C7 is going to charge too fast to control, I can increase the R14 resistor.

My biggest problem is that I have 5 V to turn on the MOSFETs but these are power MOSFETs and they need higher voltages to be fully on (V<sub>gs(th)</sub> = -4 V). The current I'm expecting is really low so maybe that's not a problem. I've tried to search for logic-level P- MOSFETs but the best I could find had a V<sub>gs(th)</sub> of -3.5 V.

I've found the SI8429DB on the internet but I don't have access to it. If you have logic-level P-MOSFET recommendations, I am open.

Question: Will the IRF4905 cause trouble with high GS threshold voltages?

Extra question: Should I short pin1 and pin2 of the LM336?

A completely different perspective would be removing everything including SW3 and letting the delay depend on the charging of the capacitor instead of the discharging. But that would keep the capacitor fully charged for the whole duration of the run. It will run for months maybe on batteries and I don't want leakage current. If the capacitor will leak more than 1 μA it's a no-go.

If I could automate charging the capacitor quickly and discharging it slowly for the delay and not letting that portion of the circuit pull any more current after that without SW3, it would be great. It's like a latch operation, charging could set something and discharging could reset it, but the S-R Latch will always be connected to power in this scenario. I don't want it to waste power after its job is done. I want a self termination.

Comment: There is no "SW2" in your diagram - is it the one at the top with no label?

Comment: Yes, sorry the picture was cropped